# How to add internal Aurelia plugin

Tags: gulp, aurelia, systemjs, jspm

I have created Aurelia plugin. in the main.js of my project i called it.

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .plugin('aurelia-kendoui-bridge',
      (kendo) => kendo.pro(),
      (kendo) =>kendo.kendoMultiselect())
    .plugin('skeleton-plugin-master');

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```

the plugin is not found.

Comment: How have you installed `skeleton-plugin-master`? Is it listed in your `config.js`? We're going to need more details before we can help you.

Comment: i have downloaded the skeleton form github. and added that as a sibling project. there is no line in the config.js that tie the plugin to the project. i need a way to do it manually in the config.js because its internal. what should i write in the config js to tell the project recognize the plugin?